# I cant print a simple JAVA code with BlueJ , works in CMD

Tags: java, printing, bluej

I am new to java, and I can't seem to figure out how I can get this simple code to work properly. I understand the code, and I have it typed exactly how the book has it. The code compiles with no errors, but it just doesn't print anything. I think the problem has to do with the main function or something, because when I right click the class in BlueJ and click on void main it will compile correctly.

Anyways, here's the code.

```
 public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in BlueJ, or is it supposed to be that way? Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. It probably appears several thousand times on the internet as the Java "hello World" example.

Comment: I am not saying that anything is wrong with the code, I actually said it worked perfectly in CMD. The real question was, "Am I doing something wrong in BlueJ?". I ask that because I can't compile that code without running this class in BlueJ in a special way. All I want is an explanation for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're ready with the code, click on the `Compile` button.

[image: first screen]

If everything is fine, you will see a message on the bottom of the screen, saying `Class compiled - no syntax errors`. Then close the screen and go back to the project palette.

Right click on the class, and pick `void main(String[] args)`. You will be prompted with a little screen, where you can provide some parameters. Don't provide any and just click `OK`.

[image: second screen]

If everything is fine, you will see the `Terminal Window` with the proper output.

[image: third screen]

**There is nothing wrong with the code, I suggest you focus on the BlueJ documentation**.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that I set everything up correctly and the code was supposed to act like this. Reading this over, it makes perfect since why I would have to execute it in this way. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the program.  That's a regular "hello world" program.

There is nothing wrong with BlueJ.  (Did you seriously think that BlueJ is incapable of running simple programs?)

There is *most likely* something wrong with the way you are *using* BlueJ ... but you've provided minimal information on that.

I suggest that you read the BlueJ documentation ... or follow this simple step-by-step example:  http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/BlueJProjectInstructions.html

(It is also possible that you've not installed BlueJ correctly, but lets not start proposing wild theories without some evidence to support them ...)

Comment: That was my concern, that I did not set BlueJ up correctly or that I did something incorrect somehow to make this simple code not work. I just wasn't aware that I had to run the code using the rightclick and main function in order to see the actual output. thanks for the help.